# Хостинг Heroky & база данных & python

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

я использую Heroku что бы разрабатывать бота для соц сети Discord( пишу на Discord.py ).
Мне понадобилось использование базы данных, и у меня возникли вопросы:

1. Какую бд можно выбрать?
2. Будет ли эта бд поддерживаться на Heroku?
3. После перезапуска проекта в Heroku, данные в базе сохранятся?

Также я сейчас попробую сделать хранилище из файловой системы, но чувствую это не сработает (

Прошу вас помочь, и сказать какую бд вы использовали если сталкивались с этой проблемой.

Comment: Если нагрузка на бота небольшая, то sqlite3. Но бд не должна распологаться на хероку, потому что каждые сутки, если не ошибаюсь, файлы на хероку удаляются и загружаются заново, так что весь прогресс вашей бд будет через день теряться.

Comment: @ClarkDevlin можно ссылку на документацию где это описано если не трудно? Первый раз услышал и что то не нахожу подтверждения)

Comment: @asanisimov https://qna.habr.com/q/569641?_ga=2.72214355.1164708322.1616401182-31028938.1579867853
в доке хз, но я это лично проверял)

в общем, оптимальный вариант postgresql использовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. MongoDB или же для python pymongo
2. Да
3. Да
   Я использую монгу из за того что в хероку не поддерживается сохранение и изменение файлов

Answer (score 1):

Я использую MySQL (плагин для heroku можно подключить бесплатно после привязки банковской карты). Но можно и без подключения плагина, если у вас есть другой сервис, который предоставляет базу данных.